# Accessing an Ember CLI app's config from within an addon

Tags: ember-cli

I'm developing an addon for Ember CLI which requires me to dynamically load files from the app. I should be able to do this with a command like `require('my-app/models/load-me')`. The only problem is that `my-app` could be anything, depending on what the developer named their application. If I had access to the `my-app/config/environment` file, I could just get the `modulePrefix` from there, but unfortunately, that's also namespaced under `my-app`.

So does anyone know of another way to access the `modulePrefix`? I'm assuming there must be a way, because Ember CLI itself needs to get that prefix before it can load any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practices-accessing-app-config-from-addon-code/7006). Basically, you can look it up through the container like so:

```
this.container.lookupFactory('config:environment').modulePrefix;
```